# In cuda, is it possible to write dense array from sparse array with expected sequence?

Tags: cuda

There is `array1` that represent 0 or 1 (for each thread block):

```
bool array1[]: [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

Each thread in thread block accesses `array1` by using `threadIdx.x`.

And, I need to make `shared dense array2 (each value represents thread ID with '1' value from array1`:

```
__shared__ bool array2[] (thread ID) : [0, 1, 4, 5]
```

It seems that, at least, I need `atomicAdd()` operation to index `array2`.

Even with `atomicAdd()`, I think that it is hard to make `array2` like above sequence

(0, 1, 4, 5).

Is it possible to make `array2` from `array1` in cuda (for each thread block)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [coalesced groups](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cooperative-groups/):

suppose the read Boolean is `threasIsIN`:

```
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
namespace cg = cooperative_groups;

uint32_t tid = threadIdx.x;
const uint32_t warpLength = 32;
uint32_t warpIdx = tid / warpLength;
if (threadIsIn){
   auto active = cg::coalesced_threads();
   uint32_t idx = active.thread_rank() + warpIdx * warpLength;
   array2[idx] = tid;
}
```

**Edit**

solution with multiple warps in a block:
the first warp of the block will prepare the shared array for the rest of warps in the block, this makes the other warps to wait for the first warp to finish.

```
thread_block block = this_thread_block();
uint32_t tid = threadIdx.x;
const uint32_t warpLength = 32;
uint32_t warpIdx = tid / warpLength;
uint32_t startIdx = 0;
uint32_t tidToWrite = tid;
uint32_t maxItr = blockSize / warpLength;
uint32_t itr = 0;
while (warpIdx == 0 && itr < maxItr){
    auto warp = cg::coalesced_threads();
    auto warpMask = warp.ballot(threadIsIn); // the tid'th bit is set to 1 if threadIsIn is true for tid
    uint32_t trueThreadsSize = __popc(warpMask); // counts the number of bits that are set to 1
    if(threadIsIn){
        auto active = cg::coalesced_threads();
        // active.size() has the same value as trueThreadsSize 
        array2[startIdx + active.thread_rank()] = tidToWrite;
    }
    startIdx += trueThreadsSize;
    tidToWrite += warpLength;
    ++itr;       
    arr1Idx += warpLength;
    threadIsIn = arr1[arr1Idx];
}
block.sync();
```

Comment: Does this operation cost a lot?

Comment: @sungjuncho it is actually quite cheap. it does not require any atmoics too. the only thing you need to take into account is the index of the active group here is limited to a warp, you may define a warp Id for each warp and rearrange your code based on the warp Id

Comment: @sungjuncho using shared memory sometimes is expensive with a good design you can outperform it.

Comment: @sungjuncho is your block size a multiple of 32?

Comment: Thank you. But the solution you described is that it is not coalesced between warps. For example, the array2 is [0,1, 4, 5, 0, 0, ..., 33, 34, ...], isn't it?

Comment: @sungjuncho yeah I am thinking to find a solution for that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197093/discussion-between-oblivion-and-sungjun-cho).

Answer (score 1):

This is in a general category of problems called **stream compaction**.  The canonical approach is to perform a prefix sum (scan operation) on a processed version of your data (converting the kept values to 1, the discarded values to 0), then use that prefix sum as the index to write to, in the output array.

[CUB](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/index.html) provides a convenient [block-level scan operation](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_scan.html), so we don't have to write our own.  Thereafter, the indexed copy is trivial:

```
$ cat t1465.cu
#include <cub/cub.cuh>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const int nTPB = 1024;
const int ds = nTPB;

__global__ void BlockCompactKernel(bool *data, int *result,  int *data_size)
{
    // Specialize BlockScan for a 1D block of nTPB threads on type int
    typedef cub::BlockScan<int, nTPB> BlockScan;
    // Allocate shared memory for BlockScan
    __shared__ typename BlockScan::TempStorage temp_storage;
    // Obtain a segment of consecutive items that are blocked across threads
    int scan_data[1];
    // load data
    bool tmp = data[threadIdx.x];
    // process data
    scan_data[0] = (tmp)?1:0;
    // scan data
    // Collectively compute the block-wide exclusive prefix sum
    BlockScan(temp_storage).ExclusiveSum(scan_data, scan_data);
    // indexed copy
    if (tmp) result[scan_data[0]] = threadIdx.x;
    // optional: return result size
    if (threadIdx.x == nTPB-1) *data_size = scan_data[0] + ((tmp)?1:0);
}



int main(){

  bool *d_data, *data = new bool[ds];
  int data_size, *d_data_size, *d_result, *result = new int[ds];
  cudaMalloc(&d_data_size, sizeof(d_data_size[0]));
  cudaMalloc(&d_result, ds*sizeof(d_result[0]));
  for (int i = 0; i < ds; i++) data[i] = (rand() > (RAND_MAX/2))?true:false;
  std::cout << "Original data:" << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i < ds; i++) std::cout << (int)data[i] << ",";
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, ds*sizeof(d_data[0]));
  cudaMemcpy(d_data, data, ds*sizeof(d_data[0]), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  BlockCompactKernel<<<1,nTPB>>>(d_data, d_result, d_data_size);
  cudaMemcpy(&data_size, d_data_size, sizeof(d_data_size[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cudaMemcpy(result, d_result, data_size*sizeof(d_result[0]), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  std::cout << std::endl << "Compacted data:" << std::endl;
  for (int i=0; i < data_size; i++) std::cout << result[i] << ",";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
$ nvcc -o t1465 t1465.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1465
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Original data:
1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,
Compacted data:
0,2,3,4,7,9,11,13,14,15,16,17,19,23,28,30,31,32,34,35,37,39,40,41,43,46,47,49,50,53,54,61,62,63,65,67,68,69,70,73,74,75,77,78,80,83,84,87,89,90,91,92,93,95,97,98,99,102,103,105,106,108,110,116,119,123,124,125,126,128,132,135,137,139,141,143,146,147,148,149,150,151,154,159,160,161,164,166,168,170,173,174,178,179,181,182,184,186,187,189,190,191,192,193,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,207,208,210,212,214,219,221,222,223,225,226,229,230,233,237,238,240,244,246,249,250,251,254,255,256,258,260,261,262,264,267,268,272,273,274,276,280,282,286,287,288,289,291,293,294,295,296,298,299,301,302,303,305,308,311,315,316,318,320,321,329,330,331,332,333,337,338,343,349,350,352,353,356,357,358,360,362,366,367,368,370,374,375,378,379,382,383,386,391,392,397,398,401,402,403,404,407,410,411,412,413,415,418,422,425,427,428,431,432,433,437,439,440,441,448,450,455,457,458,459,460,461,462,464,466,467,468,469,470,473,474,475,479,481,482,483,488,489,492,493,494,496,499,500,501,502,505,506,507,508,509,511,512,513,515,516,517,518,519,520,521,522,524,525,526,527,528,529,531,534,535,536,537,539,540,541,542,544,546,547,548,549,552,554,556,563,564,565,566,569,572,573,576,577,578,581,582,583,584,585,587,590,592,593,596,597,598,600,601,604,605,606,610,611,613,614,618,619,620,621,623,624,629,630,631,632,633,637,638,639,642,644,645,648,650,651,652,653,658,662,667,668,670,677,678,682,683,685,687,689,690,692,693,696,697,698,699,700,702,704,706,712,714,715,717,720,722,724,725,726,727,728,731,732,734,737,740,741,744,747,749,751,752,753,755,756,757,761,762,763,764,765,766,767,775,776,777,782,786,787,789,790,793,794,796,797,798,799,801,802,806,808,811,812,814,815,817,820,822,827,829,830,832,833,835,836,839,847,851,852,853,854,855,858,860,863,864,865,866,868,869,870,872,876,878,879,880,881,882,883,884,885,886,887,888,890,891,895,896,897,899,902,908,909,911,912,913,916,917,918,920,921,922,923,924,926,927,928,929,932,938,941,942,944,945,950,952,954,955,961,964,968,973,975,976,977,980,981,983,985,986,987,989,990,991,994,996,999,1001,1002,1004,1008,1011,1014,1019,1020,1021,1022,
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```